# Check if option select is empty in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="customer_id" class="text-white">Customer</label>
          <select class="form-control bg-dark text-white" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="{{ testoccasion.customer_id }}">
          {% for customer in testoccasion %}
                 {% if customer.customer_name != None  %}
                       <option {% if customer.customer_id == customer.customer_id %} selected {% endif %} value="{{ customer.customer_id }}">{{ customer.customer_name }}</option>
                 {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          </select>
     </div>
```

i have this form where im getting data from a database, but i want to check if there are no data and show something else.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, the testocassion variable should be None to make it work

```
{% if testoccasion %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customer_id" class="text-white">Customer</label>
            <select class="form-control bg-dark text-white" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="{{ testoccasion.customer_id }}">
                {% for customer in testoccasion %}
                     {% if customer.customer_name != None  %}
                           <option {% if customer.customer_id == customer.customer_id %} selected {% endif %} value="{{ customer.customer_id }}">{{ customer.customer_name }}</option>
                     {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
             </select>
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: sorry for not saying that the testoccasion  is a database that has, customer, products,testusers and testconditions. I want to have so i there are no customers in the testoccasion database it should be a "<p></p>" thats says there are no customers.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand you very well but on my understand you want to check if you have customer name or customer name = none so you can make {% else %} like the code in line 8 ,9
If i'm wrong, please tell me

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customer_id" class="text-white">Customer</label>
        <select class="form-control bg-dark text-white" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" value="{{ testoccasion.customer_id }}">
        {% for customer in testoccasion %}
               {% if customer.customer_name != None  %}
                     <option {% if customer.customer_id == customer.customer_id %} selected {% endif %} value="{{ customer.customer_id }}">{{ customer.customer_name }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                <option selected value="0">No customer</option>
               {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: you are right this works, but i want to check if the select has no option and if it dont have i want a "<p></p>" that says there are no customers. If i do like you have i done i can only have an option that says there are no customers. dont know if it is possible but.